# CMake: Get environment variable with escaped characters

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, cmake-language

Suppose one wants to use the environment variable `MY_VAR` in CMake. This may be accomplished simply by using `set(myVar $ENV{MY_VAR})`.

But what if `MY_VAR` contains escape characters, say `MY_VAR="/path/with/escaped\ chars"`? CMake treats `\` followed by a white-space as two individual characters, instead of a single character (white-space). In other words,

```
# CMakeLists.txt

set(myVar $ENV{MY_VAR})
message(${myVar})
```

prints `/path/with/escaped\ chars`, not `/path/with/escaped chars`. **How does one get CMake to recognize escape characters in environment variables? Are there any best practices regarding this problem?** I'm running CMake on macOS, but hope that there is a platform independent solution...

**Context:** Cmake is used to configure a `C++` framework before installation. The `MY_VAR` contains a path provided by the user that is used (a) in a Makefile to set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and (b) by Cmake to `configure_file` a configuration file for a python script that is required by the framework.

Comment: After trying it, it doesn't appear that CMake applies the escape character processing for `$ENV{}` variables, but it does when just using `set(myVar /path/with/escaped\ chars)`. Can you provide some more context for what you're using the path in `MY_VAR` for? For example, if you are trying to use a path containing spaces, you could wrap the path in quotes `"` after it is read in through the environment variable...

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I've added context to the question. I would rather not ask the user not to use escape characters and always use double quotes.

Comment: I should add that the question "should" have an answer regardless of the context. There must be a way to control how Cmake deals with escape characters in environment variables, right?

Comment: It is my understanding that CMake copies the backslashes (\\) from environment variables verbatim, as they are commonly used as path separators (e.g. on Windows).

Comment: `MY_VAR="/path/with/escaped\ chars"` set's MY_VAR with two distinct characters slash and space, it's the same as `MY_VAR="/path/with/escaped\\ chars"` but it really depends on your shell. What environment are you on? Windows? Linux? I think you want `MY_VAR="/path/with/escaped chars"`. The slash is there in the variable value, so it get's printed out properly.

Comment: I'm using macOS, but looking for a platform independent solution. The problem with `MY_VAR="/path/with/escaped chars"` is that `MY_VAR` can then no longer be used properly in the shell. I guess the Cmake behaviour is as expected. Apparently it's simply a bad idea to use the same environment variable in shell and Cmake context.

Comment: You could add a check for this: `if(UNIX) string(REGEX REPLACE "\\\\" "" myVar ${myVar}) endif()`, assuming there will be no back-slashes in paths in MacOS/Linux environments.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for the help! I get it now: Without the assumption that there be no backslashes in the path, this problem is unsolvable: `export MY_VAR="\\"` and `export MY_VAR="\\\\"` both yield the same `myVar` in Cmake. Therefore, Cmake cannot tell if `myVar` is supposed to be one escaped backslash, or two backslashes.